# Is there any place to set Organization object permission?

Tags: permissions

We never checked for the accessibility on organization object but by accident we put the access check on Schema.SObjectType.Organization and it fails on some user but it doesn't for other user because user don't have enough permission. This varies depending on the environment. The same user profile works( doesn't through exception when checking for accessibility on org object) but on different env it does throw. Is there any place to set the permission for organization object?

Comment: You don't set permission for this object directly. I'm pretty sure it depends on the permissions "View Setup and Configuration" and "Customize Application."

Comment: Weird SF design. What if I don't want to show user setup and configuration? They won't be allowed to see the organization object which includes company info..etc.